# Can't reference stylesheet using absolute directory path

Tags: php, path, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm trying to link to an external stylesheet using this code:

```
<?php
    include("/homepages/9/myusername/htdocs/Mobile_Detect.php");
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect();

    if($detect->isiOS()){
        // code to run for the Apple iOS platform.
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/homepages/9/myusername/htdocs/style.css" />';
    }
?>
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to establish a working link to `style.css`. I've tried this absolute path, as well as an ordinary path, formatted as if it were HTML: `href="/style.css"`, `href="style.css"`, `href="./style.css"`, and every other possibility. What am I doing wrong? How can I make this code work?

Comment: We don't know where your file is any better than you do.  Do you know what the symbols mean? A leading `/` will (I believe) start at the root of the domain. No leading slashes means start in the current directory. `./` means the same thing (`.` means "current directory") and `..` means "parent directory".

Comment: All your PHP code is doing is writing some HTML to the page, so I doubt that this is a PHP problem. Try specifying an absolute URL for the stylesheet rather than a directory path. That will also let you load the stylesheet URL in a browser window and verify that the URL is good.

Comment: I know exactly where the file is, sorry for now mentioning it. The file is in my root directory, or, as a browser would display it, "www.mydomain.com/style.css".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `href` attribute of a `style` tag is processed by a browser. Browser obviously doesn't have access to your server filesystem path `/homepages/9/whatever` (even more, it will try to load `http://yoursite/homepages/9/whatever`).

Change the value of `href` attribute with something browser is able to load (e.g. `http://yoursite/media/style.css`).

Comment: Good answer. This is clearly what I should have said in my comment.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Did you replaced the line in question with `echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.mydomain.com/style.css" />';`? Can you open `http://www.mydomain.com/style.css` with your browser?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. For whatever reason, the browser won't load it.

Comment: As for opening `www.mydomain.com/style.css` using my browser, no problems there.

Comment: Try opening your page in Google Chrome, then open Developer Tools from within it and check the actual css url in the "Elements" tab (and try to follow the link), and whether the css has been loaded on the "Resources" tab.